# How would i properly get 1 void from another form, to be used in a different form

Tags: c#, windows, forms, void

Once again i need your help.. Anywho.. I've managed to get this code below to "work". the part there doesn't work is "this". I've no idea of what to use in static and how it works. I'm rather new to this aswell, so i might need some explenation for dummies.

Anyway. This code below is suppossed to be my "mainform", where everything is loaded like icons, size, settings, menu and whatever not.

Currently i'm trying to add a global "settings". which can be loaded from all the forms. So each invidual forms would be `this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1440, 900);` and anything else i may add would have same impact on the form. like icons, opacity, whatever not.

Overally it's just a place to store settings there can be accessed from any other forms.

What i've written below here, is what i've managed so far. The SettingsOnProgramStart is recognised in my Settings form, but it does not change the Clientsize or the icon. It's pobably because of the "this" as it shows red lines.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace lala.events
    {
        public partial class TrayMenu : Form
        {
            public TrayMenu()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                SettingsOnProgramStart();
            }
        }

        public static void SettingsOnProgramStart()
        {
            //
            // Load global settings.
            //
            this.Icon = new Icon("images/skin/global/icon.ico");
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1440, 900);
        }
    }
}
```

Settings file :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace lala.events
{
    public partial class Settings : Form
    {
        public Settings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TrayMenu.SettingsOnProgramStart();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time and sorry for any problems this may have caused :/

I'd love if anyone could give me a useful link to a "configuration for dummies", where i'd learn about using cfg, ini for my project. so i can get the invidual settings loaded from a file.

Comment: Ummm... what are you trying to do?

Comment: To start with; using `this` in a static method makes no sense.... I don't understand your code at all.

Comment: changed some words, should be better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the form whose settings need to be set in:

```
public static void SettingsOnProgramStart(Form formToSet)
{
   //
   // Load global settings.
   //
   formToSet.Icon = new Icon("images/skin/global/icon.ico");
   formToSet.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1440, 900);
}
```

Used as:

```
//When called from another form
TrayForm.SettingsOnProgramStart(this);
```

As to settings, see MSDN application settings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0(v=vs.110).aspx

As an aside; this code doesn't really make sense as part of the `TrayForm` class, as its not related to that object at all. It should likely be a member of a `GlobalSettingsManager` class, or something similar.

Comment: TrayMenu is a icon menu, what my general purpose was to have the "loading parts" added in here and then retrieved from multiple forms. instead of having to add icon = something and clientsize = something, in all the forms. basically a shortcut for this.

Comment: i'm really sorry. my english isn't the best so i'm trying to explain it properly. give me a few minutes and i'll try rewrite the question in first post.

Comment: It should be easier to read now, sorry for any problems it may have caused :/

Comment: @KomariKamikita Judging by your edit; I'm fairly confident with the first option now (removed the other one). As an aside; while a `static` method probably *does* make sense here; what doesn't make sense is putting it in the `TrayForm` class. It should probably be in a `GlobalSettingsManager` class or similar (and maybe not be static, but dependency injected. Given that you are a beginner, I'll stick with `static` for now).

Comment: i see. thank you for your respond. i got a question through. how would i "use" that formToSet in another form?.

Comment: Thank you alot. this works perfectly :D.. truly thank you. i'll add this as "resolve" :)

Comment: @KomariKamikita Glad I was able to help!